# How to iterate greatest key string value first in hashmap

Tags: java, loops, hashmap

I want to iterate greatest key value first.My code is here. I have hashmap with some value .  I want to iterate greatest key value first, so that it will replace greatest key value first as per my code.

```
 HashMap<String, String> mapp=new HashMap<String, String>();
          mapp.put("ab","blue");
          mapp.put("abc","black");
          mapp.put("abcdef","green");
          mapp.put("abcd","pink");

for (Iterator it = alltyp.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
  String finalstring = (String) it.next();
   Iterator it1=mapp.entrySet().iterator();
   while(it1.hasNext())
        {
         Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry) it1.next();
         String key_ = (String) pairs.getKey();
         String value_ = (String) pairs.getValue();
         finalstring = finalstring.replaceAll(key_, value_);
         }
     }
```

First it will iterate key value "abcdef" then "abcd" then "abc" and finaly "ab". Now in while loop it will replace "abcdef" first. 
    please give me your suggetion.

Comment: The entries in `HashMap`s aren't ordered (the "normal" ordered, that is). You're going to need to do some sorting work first on the keys/entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done directly through TreeMap; you just need to pass on your own Comparator which sorts keys by length in descending order.

```
    Map<String,String> mapp = new TreeMap<String,String>(new Comparator<String>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(String paramT1, String paramT2) {
            Integer t1 = paramT1.length();
            Integer t2 = paramT2.length();
            return t2.compareTo(t1);
        }

    });
     mapp.put("ab","blue");
     mapp.put("abc","black");
     mapp.put("abcdef","green");
     mapp.put("abcd","pink");

     for(String t : mapp.keySet()){
         System.out.println(" key :"+ t);
     }
```

I have discussed about Comparators in detail on my blog; [here](http://geekrai.blogspot.in/2014/05/overriding-natural-sort-in-java.html).

Comment: can it will give greatest value in descending order?

Comment: yeah it gives;  you can test it. Just copy and paste above code in the main method and run it. Approach suggested by @Emanuel is not proper.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TreeMap` object instead of `HashMap`.

Iterating on a `TreeMap` will give you the keys in ascending order. Just push the values in a stack as you iterate and then pop them one by one then voila, you now have your keys in descending order.

```
TreeMap<String, String> mapp = new TreeMap<String, String>();
mapp.put("ab","blue");
mapp.put("abc","black");
mapp.put("abcdef","green");
mapp.put("abcd","pink");

Stack<Entry<String, String>> stk = new Stack<Entry<String, String>>();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : mapp.entrySet()) {
    stk.push(entry);
}

while (!stk.isEmpty()) {
    Entry<String, String> entry = stk.pop();
    // Do something with entry
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply.but can you give me sample code as per my code?

Comment: This is not a good approach; why do you need to store again in a stack ?

Comment: What is wrong about using a stack? Well, another solution would be to pass a Comparator.